# HTML Elements Disappear from Node List

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use javascript to find all elements with a particular css, and replace this css with another. But the strange thing is my elements' list would change after the css is removed after line:

```
element_list[i].classList.remove( "css1" );
```

```js
function change_color()
{

 debugger;
 var element_list =  document.getElementsByClassName('css1');
 
 for(var i=0; i< element_list.length; i++) 
 {
    document.getElementById('length_indicator').innerHTML += element_list.length+',';
  element_list[i].classList.remove( "css1" ); //item in control_list would be lost
    
    document.getElementById('length_indicator').innerHTML += element_list.length+',';
  element_list[i].classList.add( "css2" ); //item added to second item
 }
}

change_color();
```

```css
.css1
{
  background-color: red;
}
.css2
{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="css1">
  div 1
</div>

<div class="css1">
  div 2
</div>

<div class="css1">
  div 3
</div>

array length: <label id='length_indicator'/>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tling/3rhwrx8c/2/)

What is wrong here?

Comment: [On-Topic (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions that ask ***"Why isn't this code working?"*** must contain a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *in the question itself.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because you are getting the element's into a node list in the first place by using

```
var element_list =  document.getElementsByClassName('css1');
```

**[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** returns a "live" node list so that any any point (event after you get the list) an element gets added or removed from the DOM and that change would affect the list, the list is automatically updated.

Instead, change the line to:

```
var element_list =  document.querySelectorAll('css1');
```

**[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** returns a static node list, so the elements that it finds when the line executes are the elements that will be in that node list later on as well (assuming that an element hasn't been completely removed from the DOM).